# How to assign colors to specific raster values using R

Tags: raster, r, legend, visualisation, color-ramp

I am using the `levelplot` function of the awesome `rasterVis` package to create a map whose values diverge around zero. I am plotting a raster file using a red to blue palette, but I am trying to assign grey to zero values in the map.

Specifically, I want to reproduce the colors of this figure:

[image]

Notice that where a red to blue scale is used, but zero values have been colored with grey.

Currently, my maps looks like this:[image]

And this is the code to reproduce it (file available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/cypfdu1eaz2fuok/r.annual.tif?dl=0):

```
# Load required packages
library(rasterVis)

# open file
r.annual <- raster("Downloads/r.annual.tif")

# Set color palette
myTheme=rasterTheme(region=brewer.pal('RdBu', n=11))

# Plot
levelplot(annual.mask, par.settings=myTheme, margin=F)
```

How can I assign grey to all zero values in my map above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your own color palette by concatenating two predefined color palettes and your desired gray color as: *[red orange yellow palette]* + *[zero gray color]* + *[blues palette]*. To get zero value aligned with the gray color you have to use the same number of colors (`n`) for the predefined color palettes.

Try the commented code below:

```
# Load libraries
library('rasterVis')

# open raster file
r.annual <- raster("r.annual.tif")

# Set color palette
zeroCol <-"#B3B3B3" # (gray color, same as your figure example)
reds <- rev(brewer.pal('YlOrRd', n = 7))
blues <- brewer.pal('Blues', n = 7)

myTheme <- rasterTheme(region = c(reds, zeroCol, blues))

# Plot
levelplot(r.annual, par.settings = myTheme, margin = FALSE, main = expression("Precipitation" ~ (mm ~ year^{-1})))
```

[image: plot]

Notice that your plot won't look like the figure example you posted because your raster have more sparse data with many Nas

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized that my problem is probably too many NA's in the map. Try adding `myTheme$panel.background$col = 'grey70'` after your `myTheme` line and plot it to see the result. Apparently now I need to get rid of the excessive NA areas around the image.

Comment: You are welcome! Note that `0` value is different from `NA` value. Also they have different meanings. You can assign the same color to both, but I think It's not appropriate. If you want to have a precipitation raster that look like the figure you posted (more data), one suggestion maybe trying to interpolate your data following an appropriate prediction model.